# Is flutter is nomore takinig firebaseUser comand?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, pug, flutter-dependencies

So My problem is i want to use firebase authenticate in my app and i am trying to use this command ( Future currentUser();)
but the program not recognize the word FirebseUser ? so how can i fix this ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ6Ck.png)

Answer (score 0):

it is not a future function anymore, you can access the user directly; `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser`

Answer (score 0):

Due to the breaking changes on the firebase packages. The currentUser() is changed to the getter
**BREAKING: Accessing the current user via currentUser() is now synchronous via the currentUser getter.**
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth/changelog

so you can access the current user by using the getter method.

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

Comment: thanks ^_^ it's working now